# Giving different names to parcel dist files

Tags: node.js, parceljs

I'm using Parcel to build and run my Node.js app. Whenever I run parcel build, I always end up with two different js files.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/5018) on the Parcel bundler Github page, this is normal because one of the two has the assembly changes. The problem is that my client only needs one of them, and prefers to run the build himself. I need a way to distinguish the two files easily, so he can tell which one he needs to use (we integrate the app into a portal, and he has to copy the file over there.)

I've tried using [parcel-namer-custom](https://github.com/vseventer/parcel-namer-custom), but it doesn't seem to work for giving them distinct names - they always end up identical except for the hashes. Is there a way to fix this, or a different package that would do this for me?

I tried using this configuration with parcel-namer-custom:

```
  "parcel-namer-custom": {
    "index.js$": "index-file-[N].[hash].[ext]",
    "page2.js$": "other-file-[N].[hash].[ext]",
    ".css$": "display[N].css"
  },
```

But the [N] doesn't appear to work as regex: it just appears as-is on the dist file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that plugin, but from documenation:

> [N] the N-th match obtained from matching the current filename against the Regular Expression.

"[N]" inserts N-th match found in text (and N should be an integer). But you don't have any groups in regular expression "index.js$".

For example, if you'll use

```
"(ind)ex.js$": "index-file-[1].[hash].[ext]"
```

then file name became `index-file-*ind*.3abde34.js0` (for instance)

Comment: I gave up on the plugin and switched to using Webpack, but I can confirm that I tried that at the time and it still came out as just [1], like if it were plaintext.